# Is it possible to add a free text note to a team city build?

Tags: teamcity

I'd like to be able to add free text notes to a given build, I know I can tag builds, but I'd like to be able to add notes like:

> Deployed to client staging server 24/01/2011

If I try and do this as a series of tags teams city shows them back to me in alphabetical order, which isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See "Comment" in "Build Actions" in toolbar on build results page.
I think this is what you need.